# Writing declaration d.ts file for existing HOC

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm having problem with writing a `d.ts` file for a HOC component:
`with-apollo-client.js` wraps an component to inject a prop in. It is something like this:

```
export default App => {
  return class Apollo extends React.Component{
    render(){
       // code to get apolloClient variable omitted

       <Apollo client={apolloClient}>
    }
  }
}
```

To use it, we just do:

```
import withApolloClient from './with-apollo-client'
...
export default withApolloClient(App)
```

And in `with-apollo-client.d.ts`

```
import { ApolloClient } from 'apollo-boost';

export interface WithApolloClient {
    apolloClient: ApolloClient<any>;
}

export default <P extends WithApolloClient>(App: React.ComponentType<P>) => {
    return class Apollo extends React.Component<P> {};
};
```

And TS is complaining:

```
`Type '{ id: string; }' is not assignable to type 'Readonly<Props>'.
  Property 'apolloClient' is missing in type '{ id: string; }'.`
```

Comment: Looking into the react-apollo github, it seems to be written in TS by itself: https://github.com/apollographql/react-apollo , is there a difference from your `withApolloClient` and theirs `withApollo` HOC?

Comment: I am using nextjs and following their example here: https://github.com/zeit/next.js/tree/canary/examples/with-apollo. It is currently in JS, so when I try to import `with-apollo-client.js`, it says that I need to declare a `d.ts` file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove the interface WithApolloClient from your returned React.Component. Otherwise it will expect an apolloClient as prop. Something like this should work:

```
type Omit<T, K> = Pick<T, Exclude<keyof T, K>>;
type Subtract<T, K> = Omit<T, keyof K>;

export default <P extends WithApolloClient>(App: React.ComponentType<P>) => {
  return class Apollo extends React.Component<Subtract<P, WithApolloClient>> {};
};
```

Comment: This works. However, in the file where I'm importing the HOC, I still need import the interface to be extended (`WithApolloClient` in the following example):

`import withApolloClient, { WithApolloClient } from 'src/lib/with-apollo-client';`

`interface Props extends WithApolloClient {
    id?: string;
}`

Do I have to do this everywhere I want to use the HOC?

Comment: If you want to use the properties you need to pass the interface to the react component. So that's exactly the way to go.